# Windows command that will return the short date format of the OS

Tags: windows, date, cmd, date-format

I need a command (CMD) that will return the date format set for current user or system wide. We can change the default format or in different regions it's different format set by default so I need to find the format currently OS is using.

Main problem is I can't schedule tasks because i'm missing the date format when trying to schedule tasks.

[image]

so I need the date format not the actual date value :)

note: I saw some ways with power shell but on windows 8 and windows server 2008 power shell is not by default enabled.

Comment: Why is it that you need the format? The date and time can be retrieved in a standard form by `wmic`. Are you wanting the format in order to parse a user file?

Comment: no, when I schedule a job I have to set date but if system date format is different I can't pass 01/01/1990

Comment: Why does the date need to be set? Is this to get around a licensing issue?

Comment: documentation says it's required to provide date when using once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short date format can be retrieved from the registry.

```
>reg query "HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International" /v sShortDate

HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International
    sShortDate    REG_SZ    M/d/yyyy
```

And, for the current user:

```
>reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International" /v sShortDate

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International
    sShortDate    REG_SZ    yyyy-MM-dd
```

PowerShell is clearly the direction Microsoft has set. Perhaps it would be a good idea to enable it and learn it.

Comment: what if cmd command is running as system user? because I have task running as SYSTEM user

Comment: reading from registry works but I was expecting some kind of official command :) , will keep open a bit more the question if someone post official command else ill mark as best answer.

Comment: Shouldn't the system user also have a (possibly deviating) `reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International" /v sShortDate`?

Comment: @LotPings - Thanks. I have added it to the answer. I still do not know that the OP has any good purpose for getting the format.